# Entity Framework errors while saving base class if there is any inheritance

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, inheritance

I am using EF 6.1.  I have a model "Request" built from the wizard directly from my database.  In my context file (EMContext.vb) I have

```
Public Overridable Property Requests As DbSet(Of Request)
```

When I type in

```
        Dim db As New EMContext
    Dim req As New Request()
    With req
        .RequestedBy = "bar"
        .EventName = "Goo"
        .RequestedOn = Now
        .RequestStatusID = 1
    End With

    db.Requests.Add(req)
    db.SaveChanges()
```

everything works exactly as expected.  No problems.  It saves.
However, if I add a class (anywhere in the app)

```
    Class foo
       Inherits Request

       Public Property s As String
    End Class
```

and then run the exact same code I get

> {"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."}

Looking at the inner exception:

> {"Invalid column name 's'.
>   Invalid column name 'Discriminator'."}

Why in the heck is it even looking at the inherited class properties?
BTW, if I remove all the properties from the inherited class, I still get the Invalid Column 'Discriminator' error.

Comment: Why are you doing this? What is the purpose?

Comment: If you want to add more functionality to an Entity class you make a `Partial Class`.

Comment: I am doing this to pass data from a JSON call that includes more than just the request.  On the server side, I am breaking out the original Request class data from the inherited data and doing multiple operations with it.  However, the thing I don't get is why adding a class that inherits from the base anywhere in the code breaks the parent class.  How can creating a separate class have any impact on the base class when the inherited class isn't even referenced?

Comment: I don't want to add functionality to the base class.  I suppose I could create another class that declares the request class in it, then add the other 2 properties, but that doesn't change the fact that this behavior seem completely wrong.

Comment: Then create a custom class that the json parses to and then you can call the Entity and make it from this class.

Comment: Also, by adding instantiating the class Request inside of the submitted class means that I would need to manually read each field into the class object rather than letting the Web API take care of the posted data.

Comment: This should be filled thru serialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then create a custom class that the json parses to and then you can call the Entity and make it from this class.

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class jSonParsedObject
  'properties that match the Entity object
  'custom properties you need for other work
End Class
```

Usage:

```
Dim jsonObj As jSonParsedObject = SomeMethodThatParsesAndReturnsData()
Dim req As New Request()
With req
    .RequestedBy = jsonObj.RequestedBy
    .EventName = jsonObj.EventName
    .RequestedOn = jsonObj.RequestedOn
    .RequestStatusID = jsonObj.RequestStatusID
End With
...
```

Comment: This may work, but it means creating a custom object/class which is what I didn't want to do.  The main question still remains though. Why does creating an inherited class break EF?

Comment: It's no more than creating an inherited class. I don't know the answer to your question and so far no one else chimed in.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: It appears this just isn't possible in EF.  This was the best suggestion in that I ended up needing to build a separate class which found out is referred to as a DTO ( Data Transfer Object).